# Running OS X as a guest on Retina Macbook pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, vmware, parallels-desktop

I installed OS X 10.9 Mavericks on Parallels Desktop 10. 
and I installed Parallels Tools and gave 2 Cores, 2GB RAM and 384MB to that VM.
But It's only showing 256MB VRAM on the About Mac section.
and It's not smoothly working (giving tearing effect when scroll through Launch pad Apps). 
 
Anyone running OS X as a guest OS on Parallels or VMware fusion without any problem ? 

( I'm running on Late 2013 15" Retina Macbook Pro 2.3GHz i7, 16GB DDR3 RAM, 1TB PCI-E SSD , 2GB NVidia GT750m dedicated GPU, Host OS ( OS X 10.10.1 - Yosemite  )

Comment: I have used os x as a guest using vmware fusion, see my post about it for details on how to get started: [Incorrect keyboard mapping on OS X guest in vmware fusion](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135436/incorrect-keyboard-mapping-on-os-x-guest-in-vmware-fusion). 

I had a problem with the certain keys, but found a way to work around that.

I notice the tearing effect in launch pad too.